# Why would dwarves ride griffins?

Tags: mythical-creatures, fantasy-races

Something I noticed is that a fair amount of famous fantasy fiction depicts dwarves riding griffins (e.g. *Warhammer*, *Warcraft*). Ignoring for a moment why dwarves seem to have little difficulty operating outside of their typical subterranean habitat, why domesticate griffins in particular? Is it because, [according to real medieval bestiaries](http://bestiary.ca/beasts/beast151.htm), griffin sniff out precious metals like gold and line their nests with it?

Comment: Counterpoint: Who WOULDN'T ride a freaking griffin if they could?

Comment: Just as important: #1 How does a griffin fly with a lion's body and tail instead of a bird's body?  #2 Even if it can fly, how does it generate enough lift and velocity with an armored -- and very anti-aerodynamic -- dwarf sitting on top?

Comment: Do you want to know why certain franchises chose to pair those two creatures, why they are paired together often historically or are you looking for creative reasons why they might be a perfect fit? If so, you already have answered the question, what else do you want to know? Btw, the people that lived in Turkey 10k years ago didn't domesticate the pig because those two were such a great fit and the Germans didn't invent the car because they are the ideal car people. Sometimes (that means usually) things just need to happen somewhere first - even though initial conditions might be good

Comment: I think Warhammer and Warcraft are the only examples where dwarves ride griffins, so "fair amount" might be a stretch. Warhammer is almost certainly copying Warcraft. And why did blizzard come up with this for Warcraft? For style reasons. There was probably no deep though beyond that it looks cool. This is the same universe where orcs ride bats, and wyverns, and giant rhino things in the pre MMO warcraft series universe.

Comment: It's more likely Warcraft is  copying Warhammer, the original Warcraft started as a licenced game set in the Warhammer universe until Blizzard lost the licence.

Comment: @Sarriesfan, good point. I felt that these two examples were really just one example. And I can think of no others.

Comment: [SE is not a discussion forum](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92107/are-stack-exchange-sites-forums/92110#92110).  Your question is so open-ended that it's basically asking for an [infinite list of things](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6130/catalog-of-question-types/6139#6139), no one being any better than another, making the question [primarily opinion-based](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6436/idea-refinement-clarification-and-examples-of-vtc-reasons-for-new-users/6437#6437).

Comment: ...because horses are too tall

Comment: Dwarves would also be one of the only humanoid species that could really ride on besides a hobbit or something without breaking the things back or having it bounce off the ground.

Comment: Because an elf said they couldn't possibly be good enough to do so. So the dwarves set out to prove the elf wrong.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe the griffins build their nests in mountain regions that can't be reached by climbing or even if you'd reach them you could hardly defend against them if you are hanging in a wall at 4000 meters.

So dwarfs could build access tunnels to these nests and slowly domesticate them. The first griffins could have been discovered when the dwarves carved a watch tower out of the rocks. The guards would have fed them and in return the griffins would live near the towers. And one time a brave (and probably a bit stupid) dwarf would have tried to ride one of them.

Comment: The first dwarf did it due to peer pressure.  Did I just say "peer pressure"?  I ment to say "`BEER` pressure".

Comment: @MichaelKutz can they be charged with DRUNK DRIVING?

Answer (score 6):

Large flying animals typically need to drop from high altitudes in order to take off. Some theorize that this is how Quetzalcoatlus got off the ground.

Thus, these griffins would probably live in mountainous areas, just like dwarves. That way, you have a flying animal strong enough to carry a dwarf that lives locally and is less expensive than a mechanical aircraft (If the dwarves are as advanced as that).

Answer (score 3):

Okay, think for a minute about horses. We domesticated them thousand of years ago because of their ability to travel vast distances many times faster than we can. Griffens, and or peagasi, have the advantage of being able to fly, which is an amazing trait to harness for any species that wishes to travel, trade, or go to war. Unless there's significantly better choices in a very close proximety, there's no reason not to tame griffens.

Comment: Technically, I think we domesticated horses first because they could carry vastly larger loads than we could. Also, if you want to go faster, you have to have multiple horses. There's a reason the infantry could keep up with the cavalry on marches--horses can't go much farther than humans--just faster over short periods of time (a few hours).

Comment: @Hosch250 Fair enough. Most domesticated animals were used as beasts of burden, riding them was a secondary function.